# how to add discount to orders

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, orders, sales

How to add discount to Orders after it made.

I'm using Magento Community Edition 2.1.9.

I've tried it but I can't in prestashop its very easy in order page I can add discount in percentage or fixed price

Answer (score 0):

You can edit an order but the current order will be canceled and a new one will be created. You can then apply discounts to the order with the discount.